# Angular 15 - createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the FileSaver utility to save generated CSV file via the Angular 15 application. but always get the error shown below

> TypeError: i.createObjectURL is not a function
> at g (FileSaver.min.js:1:1642)
> at FileSaverService.save (ngx-filesaver.mjs:38:15)
> at ExportService.saveAsFile (export.service.ts:103:29)
> at ExportService.exportToCsv (export.service.ts:160:10)
> at Object.next (main.component.ts:193:32)
> at ConsumerObserver.next (Subscriber.js:91:33)
> at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:60:26)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
> at map.js:7:24
> at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)

Here is the code

```
private saveAsFile(buffer: any, fileName: string, fileType: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: fileType });
    this.fileSaverService.save(data, fileName);
}
```

I also tried using the direct download link code but I got the same error

```
 private saveAsFile(buffer: any, fileName: string, fileType: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: fileType });
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
 }
```

Can anyone help how to deal with URL.createObjectURL issue in angular 15

Answer (score 0):

I tracked the error, on the page outside Angular Application, there were javascript variables set like

```
var URL = 'https://localhost:7081/;
```

That line replaced the window.URL from function to string and passed automatically to the angular core app.

A nonsense mistake but I keep this question maybe someone else done such a mistake in the code.